# SendMail error : Can't send emails with a gmail account? XAMPP

Tags: php, windows

Hello I am trying to send an email and I get this error, using PHP mail():

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drip\class\users.class.php on line 169

This is my php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = artemkller@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\apache\logs\php_mail.log"
```

Sendmail:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=artemkller@gmail.com
auth_password=hidden
force_sender=artemkller@gmail.com
```

**What's wrong with this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the  port  for SMTP to 465.

Comment: It is now loading forever, any idea why?

Comment: Can you specify please? What's loading forever? Is the mail not sending?

Comment: For some reason, it gives no error now,  but mails won't arrive, not even spam folder?

Comment: Have you had a look at the logs? What errors are you seeing if any?

Comment: 13.05.02 00:00:23 : Cannot open file "C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log".  The process can not access the file because this file is used by another process

Comment: Put the server offline, the open the file/